# How to differentiate similar clusters in the mcsqs output in ATAT?

Tags: special-quasirandom-structures, alloy-theoretic-automated-toolkit

Consider the following `bestcorr.out` file:

```
2   0.866025    -0.000000   0.000000    -0.000000
2   0.866025    0.000000    -0.000000   0.000000
2   0.866025    -0.000000   0.000000    -0.000000
2   1.000000    -0.000000   0.000000    -0.000000
2   1.000000    -0.000000   -0.000000   -0.000000
2   1.000000    -0.000000   0.000000    -0.000000
2   1.414214    -0.000000   0.000000    -0.000000
2   1.414214    -0.000000   -0.000000   -0.000000
2   1.414214    0.006944    0.000000    0.006944
Objective_function= -1.630678
```

This was for a BCC ternary SQS. Let's consider the 1st nearest neighbour (NN) pairs. There are three of them; how do we differentiate among them?

Here is the part of `clusters.out` that concerns these pairs:

```
4
0.86603
2
1.50000 0.50000 0.50000 1 0
1.00000 -0.00000 1.00000 1 0

8
0.86603
2
1.50000 0.50000 0.50000 1 1
1.00000 -0.00000 1.00000 1 0

4
0.86603
2
1.50000 0.50000 0.50000 1 1
1.00000 -0.00000 1.00000 1 1
```

It might be helpful to see the [mcsqs manual page](https://www.brown.edu/Departments/Engineering/Labs/avdw/atat/manual/node47.html) and [corrdump manual page](https://www.brown.edu/Departments/Engineering/Labs/avdw/atat/manual/node35.html).

Why are there 3 different kinds of pairs with the same distance? At first, I thought in a ternary alloy it could mean AB, BC, and CA pairs. A, B, and C being constituent atoms. Now that I think of it, that doesn't make sense else it would apply to triangles and higher clusters as well but it doesn't.

Comment: +1. MathJax can slow down the loading of a page, so using MathJax for things like $3$ and $1^{st}$ is not necessary. I made the appropriate edits to remove these!

Comment: Do you have any update on this? It was asked more than 1 year ago and hasn't seen much attention since then. Did you find out anything during this time?

Comment: This post appears to be abandoned. It can be reopened if OP responds to questions/suggestions in the comments.